# How to spell 'aumenace'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm very dyslectic, and English is not my native language, I'm looking for the spelling of a word that I'm pretty sure exists, but I'm starting to have my doubts as I can't seem to find it anywhere.
The word sounds like (I think) au-menace, with 'au' as in 'audience', and then menace.
Or maybe it's rather more like awe-menace, where 'awe' is like in 'awesome'.
In any case, the word means, if I'm not mistaken, menacing (an an adjective) but in a sort of looming, impending or imposing way.

Comment: English is not your native language and yet you post a question correctly using such relatively obscure words as _looming_ and _impending_? Kudos to you!

Comment: Would the people closevoting as “General Reference” kindly explain how in the world the OP is expected to look a word **whose spelling he does not know?** Kindly show us the General Reference that allows for the necessary **lazy/approximate/fuzzy phonetic matching**, because I’d really like to use it—and I bet a lot of other people would too. Even better, would the people closevoting as “Primarily Opinion-Based” kindly explain how it is that spelling has come to be an unanswerable matter primarily of mere opinion, impression, conjecture, hypothesis, attitude, speculation, and viewpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would surely be ***ominous***, pronounced `/ˈɒmɪnəs/`, `/ˈɑmɪnəs/`, or `/ˈɔmɪnəs/`, depending.  It is related to the word *omen*, and per the OED means:

> - Of the nature of an omen, serving to foretell the future, presaging events to come, portentous.
> - Of ill omen, foreboding evil, inauspicious.

Comment: I know I wasn't making this up, just mistaken the source, thought it came from menace... Thanks, this word actually fits better then I thought.